# Сортировка массива с англ. и русскими словами?

Tags: php, сортировка

Есть такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Yury
    [1] => Maxim
    [2] => Юденок
    [3] => Мыков
)
```

Как его сортировать так чтобы 1-м были русские слова в алфавитном порядке, потом английские?

```
sort($arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
    [0] => Maxim
    [1] => Yury
    [2] => Мыков
    [3] => Юденок
)
```

Вот так, но хотелось бы чтобы русские слова были сверху.

Comment: в php конечно, навалом всяческого хлама, и может быть даже есть функция, интересующая вас, но все же весьма вероятно, что ее там нет. Почему бы не написать свою? Это же элементарно

Comment: Ну может быть для вас элементарно.

Comment: простите, а в чем проблема? Вы не знаете ни одного метода сортировки? Или не знаете, как отличить латинские символы от кириллических?

Comment: 2-ое, я понимаю что у них код есть, но как это сделать не очень.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ахтунг! Приведенный мной пример -
> далек от идеального.

Всю эту беду, [можно потестить тут](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/240-7jp).

```
$arr = array(
    'Петя',
    'Yury',
    'Maxim',
    'Юденок',
    'Мыков',
    'Obama',
    'Артем',
    'Янукович',
    'Яша',
    'Gerome'
);

function abc($a,$b){
    $la = mb_substr($a,0,1,'utf-8');
    $lb = mb_substr($b,0,1,'utf-8');
    if(ord($la) > 122 && ord($lb) > 122){
        return $a > $b ? 1 : -1;
    }
    if(ord($la) > 122 || ord($lb) > 122) {
        return $a < $b ? 1 : -1;
    }

}
uasort($arr, 'abc'); // или usort(), если сохранение ключей не важно
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
// результат:
Array
(
    [6] => Артем
    [4] => Мыков
    [0] => Петя
    [3] => Юденок
    [7] => Янукович
    [8] => Яша
    [9] => Gerome
    [5] => Obama
    [2] => Maxim
    [1] => Yury
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Знаю, что не самое идеальное решение, но все же, может быть, новичкам пригодится. Сортирует по началу строки, после чего может идти, что угодно, кроме переноса строки (".,!- и т. д.). В случае чего, подкорректируете под себя.

Отличается от ответа Deonis тем, что адекватно сортирует латиницу по алфавиту.

```
function localeSort($a,$b)
{
    if (preg_match('/^([а-яё.])+/ui', $a) && preg_match('/^([a-z.])+/ui', $b)) {
        return -1;
    } elseif (preg_match('/^([a-z.])+/ui', $a) && preg_match('/^([а-яё.])+/ui', $b)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return $a < $b ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, вам стоит сделать отдельную функцию, которая будет получать массив и сортировать его уже по вашим критериям.  А именно, принимать в качестве аргумента массив и callback, который будет представлять сбой функцию-компаратор для того, чтобы ваша функция сортировки "знала" как сравнивать элементы массива. Не особо знаком с php, но думаю, там есть возможность организовать нечто подобное. 
Внутри основной функции реализуете алгоритм сортировки [Выбирайте любой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8#.D0.A1.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.BA_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D1.81.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B8)
Функция-компаратор должна определять алгоритм сравнения элементов массива с учетом сравнения по алфавиту. Что касается сравнения по алфавиту, то вам тут может помочь простое регулярное выражение наподобие такого: '/[a-z]/i' (если допустить, что каждое слово  в массиве состоят либо только из символов кириллицы, либо латиницы), либо потребуется сравнивать слова посимвольно - более чем уверен, что в php есть функции, которые позволяют получить код символа

Answer (score 1):

Ну или если не хочется писать свой велосипед, воспользуйтесь функцией [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php). В неё передаются массив и callback-функция, сравнивающая два элемента массива. Сравнивать строки можно и обычным оператором `>` или `<`, при это строка "Кирилл" будет больше строки "Kirill".

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант:

```
function abc_sortcyr($a, $b)
{
    $am = Ord(substr($a, 0, 1)) > 122;
    $bm = Ord(substr($b, 0, 1)) > 122;
    
    if($am == $bm) return strcasecmp($a, $b);
    else return $am && !$bm ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Так работает тоже:

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
     if (ToUpper($a) == ToUpper($b)) {
        return 0;
     }
     return (ToUpper($a) < ToUpper($b)) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]